# "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" error

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a problem with the f statement, because it's returning to me this error message : *"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"*
I have a dataframe called data.summary, and I want to create two new variable *vol.up* and *vol.down* depending on the other variable of my dataframe.
This is my script code :

```
data.summary <- call.dat12[,c("Dur...ms.", "Handset.Manufacturer",
                          "Src.Dst.Sig.Vol..Bytes.", "Dst.Src.Sig.Vol..Bytes.",
                          "group", "Src.Node.Type", "Dst.Node.Type")]

if (data.summary$Src.Node.Type == "eNodeB"){
  data.summary$vol.up <- data.summary$Src.Dst.Sig.Vol..Bytes. 
  data.summary$vol.down <- data.summary$Dst.Src.Sig.Vol..Bytes.
} else {
  data.summary$vol.up <- data.summary$Dst.Src.Sig.Vol..Bytes. 
  data.summary$vol.down <- data.summary$Src.Dst.Sig.Vol..Bytes.
}
```

I don't really inderstand why f statement doesn't work for vector ?
Thank in advance

Comment: Did any of these questions help you http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22the+condition+has+length+%3E+1%22

Comment: Not really, I already saw them

Comment: `data.summary$Src.Node.Type` will be a vector with the same number of items as there are rows in `data.summary`. You probably want two different `ifelse` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is a TRUE/FALSE vector with more than one element, for the `if` - `else` to work it is usually necessary a length-one logical vector that is not `NA`. Maybe what you need is to vectorize the conditions:

```
ind <- data.summary$Src.Node.Type == "eNodeB"
data.summary$vol.up<- NA
data.summary$vol.down<- NA
#for true
data.summary$vol.up[ind]<- data.summary$Src.Dst.Sig.Vol..Bytes.[ind]
data.summary$vol.down[ind] <- data.summary$Dst.Src.Sig.Vol..Bytes.[ind]
data.summary
# for false
data.summary$vol.up[!ind]<- data.summary$Dst.Src.Sig.Vol..Bytes.[!ind]
data.summary$vol.down[!ind] <- data.summary$Src.Dst.Sig.Vol..Bytes.[!ind]
data.summary
```

Comment: That's not correct.  From `?\`if\``, the condition in defined as *A length-one logical vector that is not NA. Conditions of length greater than one are accepted with a warning, but only the first element is used. Other types are coerced to logical if possible, ignoring any class.*

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work perfecty. But I don't inderstand why the "if else" doesn't work ? could you give me an example, Thanks.

Comment: Try this: x=5;
if (x==5) print("correct!") else print("is false"); #works;

x=c(3,5);
if (x==5) print("correct!") else print("is false"); #incorrect!;

for(i in seq_along(x)) if (x[i]==5) print("correct!") else print("is false") #works;